# Some doubts about the first part of the proof of Lemma 1.10 in Introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee, 2nd edition.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have some doubts about the first part of the proof of **Lemma 1.10** in **Introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee**, 2nd edition.

**Lemma 1.10. Every topological manifold has a countable basis of precompact coordinate balls.**

**Proof**. Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. First we consider the special case in which $M$ can be covered by a single chart. Suppose $\varphi: M \to \hat U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a global coordinate map, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collection of all open balls $B_r(x)\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $r$ is rational, $x$ has rational coordinates, and $B_{r'}(x)\subseteq  \hat U$ for some $r' > r$. Each such ball is precompact in $\hat U$, and it is easy to check that $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the
topology of $\hat U$. Because $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that the collection of sets of the form $ \varphi^{-1}(B)$ for$ B \in \mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the topology of $M$; consisting of precompact coordinate balls, with the restrictions of $\varphi$ as coordinate maps.

**My questions are**

**1) Why do we need to consider another ball $"B_{r'}(x)\subseteq  \hat U$ for some $r' > r$"?Is the $x$ in $B_r(x) $ the same as the $x$ in   $B_{r'}(x)$ ?**   It makes more sense to me that $r' < r$, so that there is enough room for the closure of $B_{r}$ in $U$ to stay inside $\hat U$, because if I close a set in $\hat U$, the closure cannot get out of $\hat U$, can it? Can someone clear this up?

**2)"... Each such ball is precompact in $\hat U$". My proof of this is:** The closure of an open ball in $\hat U$ is obviously closed in $\hat U$  and since an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ :closed + bounded equals compact, we have that the closure of $B_{r}(x)$ in $\hat U$  is compact, therefore $B_{r}(x)$ is precompact.  **Is this correct?**

**3) How do I check that $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the topology of $\hat U$?** **My try:** The set $\mathscr{B}$  is a countable basis for $\hat U$ if it is made of open subsets  of $\hat U$ and  any open set of $\hat U$ is a countable union of elements of $\mathscr{B}$. So because of the first requisite open subsets of $\hat U$ should have the form : $\hat U \cap U$ with U some open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$, right? And how do I prove the second requisite?

thank you!

Comment: To be sure that the closure of $B_r(x)$ is in $\hat U$, you have to put something between them: some $A$ such that you know that $\bar B_r(U) \subset X \subset \hat U$. The author just takes $A=B_{r'}(x)$. (Draw a picture). The closed ball $\bar B_r(x)$ are compact precisely because they are closed and bounded in a finite dimensional vector space. Finally, the countability is not a problem at all, and to show that it is a basis, you just have to show that any open ball is the union of such rational balls. This is classical: it is a union of all rational ball that are contained inside

Comment: @Didier Did you mean A instead of X? and "B_r(x)" instead of  "B_r(U)" ?

Comment: regarding 1), maybe you are getting lost in notation or something? You just have to choose $r$ small enough so that the ball is a subset of $\hat{U}$.

regarding 2), you have to be careful and understand better the subtleties of the subspace topology. For example, suppose that $\hat{U}$ is the open ball centered at the origin of radius $1$. Then for example the closure of $\hat{U}$ in $\hat{U}$ is $\hat{U}$ itself, but $\hat{U}$ is not closed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is why you try to keep away from the boundary, basically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the order:

1 and 2: If $r<r'$, then $B_r(x)\subset B_{r'}(x)$ (draw a picture).
In turns out that in fact we also have $\bar B_r(x) \subset B_{r'}(x)$.
Since a closed ball in a finite dimensional vector space is compact, if $r'$ is chosen such that $B_{r'}(x) \subset \hat U$, then $B_r(x)$ is precompact in $\hat U$: its closure in $\hat U$ is precisely $\bar B_r(x)$, which is compact.

As mentioned my @Malkoun in the comment section, putting $B_{r'}(x)$ between $B_r(x)$ and $\hat U$ prevents you from being too close to the boundary of $\hat U$.
If $A\subset \hat U$, the closure of $A$ **in $\hat U$** is not the usual closure $\bar A$ you know in $\Bbb R^n$, but $\bar A \cap \hat U$.
Staying away from the boundary ensures that these two notions of closure are the same.

3: The balls (all the balls) in $\hat U$ form a basis of the topology (that is, any open subset of $\hat U$ is a union of balls).
To show that the rational balls (whose centre has rational coordinates as well as the radius) form a basis of the topology of $\hat U$, it suffices to show that any ball $B_R(z)\subset \hat U$ is the union of such rational balls.
As a consequence of the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, it holds that
$$B_R(z) = \bigcup_{(x,r) \text{ rationals such that } B_r(x)\subset \hat B_R(z)}B_r(x).$$
(Approach the coordinates of $z$ by some close rationals, etc.)
To conclude, just invoke the fact that the map defined on the set of rational balls in $\hat U$ by $B_r(x) \mapsto (x,r)\in \Bbb Q^{n+1}$ is injective, and thus there are only countably many rational balls in your basis of the topology.

Comment: How do you conclude from the injectivity of the map that there coutably many balls?

Comment: @mathlover If $X$ is a set, $Y$ an at most countable set and if there exists an injective map $X\to Y$, then $X$ is at most countable. Roughly speaking an injection from $X$ to $Y$ means that "$X$ is smaller than $Y$". Note that $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$ is countable.

Comment: Instead of considering balls  of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that there is something between them and $\hat U$ as the balls of the basis in $\hat U$, couldn't the author have taken as balls of the basis in the  $\hat U$ subspace, the intersection of balls of $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $\hat U$? (because a basis of  a subspace is the intersection of the subspace with a basis of the space, isn't it?)

Comment: @mathlover If seeking for a basis of precompact open subsets, no. Counterexample: in $\Bbb R^2$, let $\hat U = B_1(0,0)$. Then the open subset $B_1(0,\frac{1}{2}) \cap \hat U$ is not precompact in $\hat U$. Again, I advise you to draw a picture

Comment: isn't $B_1(0,\frac{1}{2})\cap \hat U =B_1(0,\frac{1}{2})\cap  B_1(0,0)= \hat U$? and the closure of $\hat U$ in $\hat U$, is $\hat U$ itself, which is closed so it is precompact in $\hat U$

Comment: @mathlover Please, draw a picture, what you said is false. Moreover, $\hat U$ is never precompact in $\hat U$ if it is an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Precompact means with compact closure.

Comment: $\hat U$ is closed and open as a subspace itself

Comment: When talking about the closure in $\hat U$ , I believe I have to consider it as a space with the subspace topology

Comment: @mathlover I never said the contrary. I said that it is not compact. I think you should learn a bit more on the subspace topology, precompactness etc.

Comment: but isn't compact = closed + bounded (in finite dimensional  metric spaces)?, You agree $\hat U$ it is closed in $\hat U$, and it is bounded, where is the mistake?

Comment: @mathlover No. A subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed an bounded. Subset of $\hat U$, with the subset topology, are not in the setting of this characterization. Compactness is a more general definition for topological spaces, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).

Comment: Ok I wanted to avoid using coverings, since we are in $\mathbb{R^n}$, So compact = closed + bounded   does not hold even if $\hat U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$, therefore homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$?,  I thought they should "behave the same"

Comment: @mathlover Your homeomorphism will not be an isometry, and $\hat U$ is certainly not bounded if considered as "$\Bbb R^n$ endowed with the euclidean distance" through this homeomorphism. What you said would imply "$\Bbb R^n$ is compact since it is homeomorphic to some bounded subset", and is indeed plain wrong